# Is there any point in activating Windows?

Tags: windows-7

When I was installing Windows 7, it asked me for the license key. I didn't type anything and pressed Next. A message popped up asking me if I would like to enter the license key later. I pressed Yes, and every day at the system tray it had a picture of some keys saying "You have 30 days left to activate Windows" (and the number kept decreasing every single day). After I had 0 days left, every time I start Windows, it comes up with this message: [image]

I simply press "Ask me later" and it still works and I'm getting all the Windows Updates. It's been over a year and it still works

Question 1: Will Windows EVER stop working?

Question 2: Is this legal?

PS: The ISO is a legal download of Windows directly from Microsoft's servers

Comment: Sure it's legal, if you have purchased a key but are just too lazy to enter it?

Comment: Windows is basically "trialware" without a key, after 30 days it starts bugging you and disables your background, it will continue to do that forever with pop-ups and black background telling you it is not genuine. And yes, it is a violation of the law as you using a piece software outside of it's licensing agreement and did not purchase it.

Comment: I think it locks you out after 180 days... but I've never tested it to find out.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've had it for over a year now so yeah

Comment: it is illegal, the 30days are time to activate Windows (give you time if you have no phone or internet available at install time), not trial days. Some updates/software like MSE are only downloaded on activated systems.

Comment: 120 days is legal...http://www.tweaktown.com/news/13034/legal_way_to_run_windows_7_unactivated_for_120_days/index.html

Comment: @Moab again, **NO**. This is the time to Activate Windows if you have a legal license, no free trial!